# A (elementary) summary of the relation between algebraic curves and Riemann Surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I am interested in researching the links between these two topics but have no experience with Riemann Surfaces. What does it mean for a surface to be Riemann type and why does this link to algebraic curves.

Comment: A Riemann surface is essentially a topological manifold of real dimension 2 where all of the transition functions $\phi_i \circ \phi_j^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ are holomorphic. Let $P(z,w)$ be a polynomial in two complex variables and let $S$ be the set of points where $P$ vanishes. If $P$ satisfies the property that at every point, at least one of its partial derivatives, $P_w$ or $P_z$, is non-zero, then the vanishing set of $P$ naturally has the structure of a Riemann surface. You can read more about this in Simon Donaldson's book "Riemann Surfaces".

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71344/why-are-riemann-surfaces-algebraic-curves?rq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82129/riemann-surfaces-are-algebraic?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I think that the two links in the comment of Moishe Kohan will give you more information, but let me tell a little about it.

Riemann surfaces are by definition complex manifold of $\mathbb{C}$-dimension $1$. Thus they are of $\mathbb{R}$-dimension $2$, that's why they are (initially) called "surfaces".

Now, a theorem states that any **compact** Riemann surface can be embedded into $\mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C}$ for some $n\geq 1$ (in fact, $n=3$ works for all of them!). Then Chow's theorem tells you that any closed submanifold $X\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ is **algebraic**, that is $X$ is given as the zero locus of homogeneous polynomials. So this way you can see that all **compact** Riemann surfaces are algebraic.

Conversely, if you consider an algebraic curve in $C\subset\mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C}$, given as the zero locus of some homogeneous polynomials, **and** if $C$ has no singularities (which is translated by a criterion on the rank of the jacobian matrix of the polynomials) then $C$ inherits a structure of Riemann surface : on the charts of $\mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{C}$, the curve $C$ is given as the zero locus of polynomials, which are holomorphic.

If you want to go further in this "$\mathbb{C}$-manifold / $\mathbb{C}$-variety" correspondance, you should give a look at the really beautiful Serre's GAGA principle.

Another direction of interest, linked with your question, might be "When does a real surface (or manifold) admits a complex structure ?" which is an important question, for example in symplectic geometry (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold).